# EF6 Many-to-Many Relation Duplicate Entries on Add

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, repository-pattern

My data has a many-to-many relation between `Exhibitions` and `Markets`.
When creating a new Exhibition, some existing markets should be assigned to it.
I created a generic repository which looks like this:

```
public virtual TDto Create(TDto data)
{
        TEntity entity = ToEntity(data);
        DbEntityEntry<TEntity> dbEntity = Context.Entry<TEntity>(entity);
        dbEntity.State = EntityState.Added;
        UpdateReferences(data, dbEntity);
        Context.SaveChanges();
        data = ToModel(dbEntity.Entity);
        return data;
}
```

The idea is to allow each concrete repository to define it's own handling for updating it's references to other entities.

```
protected override void UpdateReferences(Exhibition model, DbEntityEntry<Model.EventManagement.Exhibition> entity)
{
    entity.Entity.Markets = new List<Model.EventManagement.Market>();
    foreach (var market in model.Markets)
    {
        var marketEntity = Context.Markets.Single(m => m.Id == market.Id);
        entity.Entity.Markets.Add(marketEntity);
    }
}
```

The problem that occures is, that the associated markets are duplicated when i create a new Exhibition with markets that already exist. My Context uses the following setup:

```
Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

So, my question is how to convince EF to associate the existing markets, instead of creating duplicates?

I read a lot about using ID properties alongside navigation properties to avoid this kind of problems, but with many-to-many relations this does not seem to be an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.
It's all about when the `State` is set to `Added`. I Just needed to swap `UpdateReferences` and `State = Added`.

```
public virtual TDto Create(TDto data)
{
    TEntity entity = ToEntity(data);
    DbEntityEntry<TEntity> dbEntity = Context.Entry<TEntity>(entity);
    // call UpdateReferences first...
    UpdateReferences(data, dbEntity);
    // ...then set the State to Added
    dbEntity.State = EntityState.Added;
    Context.SaveChanges();
    data = ToModel(dbEntity.Entity);
    return data;
}
```

Although it works now as expected, it's very confusing since i thought setting the State afterwards would also set the child States to Added, but apparently not... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

When you change `State` of an `Entry` to `Added`, the Entry's State and all it's relation's State will be changed to `Added`. So there is no need to add those relations separately.

So comment the line `UpdateReferences(data, dbEntity);` in your `Create` method and everything should works just fine.

Comment: My problem is that the existing Markets are not associated with the created Exhibition, instead the Markets are created as duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I sense some problem with the line

```
entity.Entity.Markets = new List<Model.EventManagement.Market>();
```

placed after

```
dbEntity.State = EntityState.Added;
```

can you try the following, in the constructor of your entity:

```
public Exhibition() {
    Markets = new List<Model.EventManagement.Market>();
}
```

then :

```
protected override void UpdateReferences(
      Exhibition model, 
      Model.EventManagement.Exhibition entity)
{
    foreach (var market in model.Markets)
    {
        var marketEntity = Context.Markets.Single(m => m.Id == market.Id);
        entity.Markets.Add(marketEntity);
    }
}
```

if it don't work as is, may be enabling proxy is the key.